# How to override list function of ModeViewSet to filter multiple value of same parameters in Django?

Tags: python, django, query-string

Currently this how my code looks -

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        query_dict = QueryDict(request.META['QUERY_STRING'])
        query_dict = query_dict.dict()
        self.queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**query_dict)
        return super().list(reuqest)
```

Now if I invoke the endpoint with the api like `/api/url/?param1=79&param2=34` it works fine. Assuming `param1` and `param2` are two fields present in `MyModel`. But if try to do this - `/api/url/?param1=79&param2=34&param1=45&param2=576` it returns the result of `param1=45` AND `param2=576`. Which is understandable since I am using dict to parse query params.

But I want the results of `param1=79&param2=34&param1=45&param2=576` combination. How to achieve that?

Which will translate to

```
SELECT *
FROM ModelTable
WHERE
param1 = 79
AND param2 = 34
AND param1 = 45
AND param2 = 576
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```py
params1 = request.query_params.getlist('param1', '')
```

Comment: I will get the list of values for `param1` but how can I pass them to `filters`.

Comment: make your dict like this `{'params1__in': params1, 'params2__in': params2}`. on the other hand, the `where` clause with `and` operator for a column doesn't work. this expression (`param1=x and param1=y`) is wrong and it never returns any rows.